# twitter Bootstrap prevent datetimepicker value being greater than another datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a form with twitter bootstrap using two datetimepickers.  I want to make it so the value of the "start_time" one can't be greater than the "end_time"one.  This should be relatively simple, but I don't seem to be retrieving the values to make the comparison correctly.

```
 $('#start_time')
    .datetimepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(ev){
        if (ev.date.valueOf('#start_time') > date.valueOf('#end_time')){
            alert("start time may not be greater than end time");
        }
    });
```